# .Net Framework 4.0 Compatiblity with Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version

I have an application that requires the .NET Framework 4.0. The application supports running on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012, which both include the .NET Framework 4.5 as a part of the operating system.

Does my application installer still need to install the .NET Framework 4 on these operating systems even though the .NET Framework 4.5 is already installed?

Comment: Why do you require the version 4 if you also require version 4.5 as an indirect prerequisite? A simple solution would be to require 4.5 if you know that only machines running 4.5+ are supported anyway.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114334/1166450).

Comment: @AlexanderSimonov thanks for pointing it out,looking over it thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net Framework 4.5 replaces 4.0; it is backward compatible so no, you don't need to install 4.0.